# How do I detect when my system wakes up from suspend via DBus or similar in a python app?

Tags: python, power-management, suspend, programming, dbus

In a background Python script I need to detect, when the system just woke up from suspend. What is a good way that does not rely on a [root script](https://askubuntu.com/q/8112/17789) but rather on python modules such as DBus?

I'm new to dbus so I could really use some example code. From what I read it's related to

```
org.freedesktop.UPower /org/freedesktop/UPower org.freedesktop.UPower.Resuming
```

Can anyone help me out with some code that connects the resuming signal to callback?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is some example code that answers my question:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# This is some example code on howto use dbus to detect when the system returns
#+from hibernation or suspend.

import dbus      # for dbus communication (obviously)
import gobject   # main loop
from dbus.mainloop.glib import DBusGMainLoop # integration into the main loop

def handle_resume_callback():
    print "System just resumed from hibernate or suspend"

DBusGMainLoop(set_as_default=True) # integrate into main loob
bus = dbus.SystemBus()             # connect to dbus system wide
bus.add_signal_receiver(           # defince the signal to listen to
    handle_resume_callback,            # name of callback function
    'Resuming',                        # singal name
    'org.freedesktop.UPower',          # interface
    'org.freedesktop.UPower'           # bus name
)

loop = gobject.MainLoop()          # define mainloop
loop.run()                         # run main loop
```

See the [dbus-python tutorial](http://dbus.freedesktop.org/doc/dbus-python/doc/tutorial.html#receiving-signals).

Comment: This does not seem to work anymore. Also, I could not find that signal in the [UPower API Docs](https://upower.freedesktop.org/docs/UPower.html#UPower.signals). Seems like the next answer points in the right direction: The signals are now provided by `org.freedesktop.login1.Manager`.

Answer (score 7):

The login1 interface provides the signal now. Here is the modified code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# slightly different code for handling suspend resume
# using login1 interface signals
#
import dbus      # for dbus communication (obviously)
import gobject   # main loop
from dbus.mainloop.glib import DBusGMainLoop # integration into the main loop

def handle_sleep_callback(sleeping):
  if sleeping:
    print "System going to hibernate or sleep"
  else:
    print "System just resumed from hibernate or suspend"

DBusGMainLoop(set_as_default=True) # integrate into main loob
bus = dbus.SystemBus()             # connect to dbus system wide
bus.add_signal_receiver(           # defince the signal to listen to
    handle_sleep_callback,            # name of callback function
    'PrepareForSleep',                 # signal name
    'org.freedesktop.login1.Manager',   # interface
    'org.freedesktop.login1'            # bus name
)

loop = gobject.MainLoop()          # define mainloop
loop.run()                         # run main loop
```

Comment: works fine. I noted that it seems unnecessary to run the `gobject.MainLoop()` if you're running a Gtk main loop.