# Laptop powers itself back on after suspend, but only when plugged in

Tags: 16.04, suspend, power-management, battery, acpi

I'm running Ubuntu 16.04. I can put my laptop into suspend by several methods (`pm-suspend`, Cinnamon power menu, suspend hardware button).

This works as expected when the laptop is running on battery, but when I suspend it while plugged in to AC power, it turns itself back on a few seconds later. When booted into Windows, however, suspend works normally on AC power.

**UPDATE:** `/var/log/pm-suspend.log` shows nothing at all.

Here's what I see in `/var/log/syslog`: power appears to resume immediately after suspending 3/4 CPU cores.

```
Feb  7 21:18:46 localhost systemd[1]: Starting Suspend...
Feb  7 21:18:46 localhost systemd-sleep[9741]: Failed to connect to non-global ctrl_ifname: (nil)  error: No such file or directory
Feb  7 21:18:46 localhost systemd-sleep[9743]: /lib/systemd/system-sleep/wpasupplicant failed with error code 255.
Feb  7 21:18:46 localhost systemd-sleep[9741]: Suspending system...
Feb  7 21:18:53 localhost kernel: [ 3992.819765] PM: Syncing filesystems ... done.
Feb  7 21:18:53 localhost kernel: [ 3992.850579] PM: Preparing system for sleep (mem)
Feb  7 21:18:53 localhost kernel: [ 3992.851319] Freezing user space processes ... (elapsed 0.002 seconds) done.
Feb  7 21:18:53 localhost kernel: [ 3992.854001] Freezing remaining freezable tasks ... (elapsed 0.001 seconds) done.
Feb  7 21:18:53 localhost kernel: [ 3992.855268] PM: Suspending system (mem)
Feb  7 21:18:53 localhost kernel: [ 3992.855289] Suspending console(s) (use no_console_suspend to debug)
Feb  7 21:18:53 localhost kernel: [ 3992.859005] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Synchronizing SCSI cache
Feb  7 21:18:53 localhost kernel: [ 3992.863965] usb 1-1.4: disconnecting
Feb  7 21:18:53 localhost kernel: [ 3992.866889] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Stopping disk
Feb  7 21:18:53 localhost kernel: [ 3993.508191] PM: suspend of devices complete after 652.621 msecs
Feb  7 21:18:53 localhost kernel: [ 3993.524058] PM: late suspend of devices complete after 15.849 msecs
Feb  7 21:18:53 localhost kernel: [ 3993.525021] ehci-pci 0000:00:1d.0: System wakeup enabled by ACPI
Feb  7 21:18:53 localhost kernel: [ 3993.525191] ehci-pci 0000:00:1a.0: System wakeup enabled by ACPI
Feb  7 21:18:53 localhost kernel: [ 3993.525194] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: System wakeup enabled by ACPI
Feb  7 21:18:53 localhost kernel: [ 3993.540020] PM: noirq suspend of devices complete after 15.957 msecs
Feb  7 21:18:53 localhost kernel: [ 3993.540490] ACPI: Preparing to enter system sleep state S3
Feb  7 21:18:53 localhost kernel: [ 3993.540762] ACPI : EC: EC stopped
Feb  7 21:18:53 localhost kernel: [ 3993.540763] PM: Saving platform NVS memory
Feb  7 21:18:53 localhost kernel: [ 3993.540768] Disabling non-boot CPUs ...
Feb  7 21:18:53 localhost kernel: [ 3993.541121] Broke affinity for irq 16
Feb  7 21:18:53 localhost kernel: [ 3993.541125] Broke affinity for irq 23
Feb  7 21:18:53 localhost kernel: [ 3993.541132] Broke affinity for irq 27
Feb  7 21:18:53 localhost kernel: [ 3993.541139] Cannot set affinity for irq 37
Feb  7 21:18:53 localhost kernel: [ 3993.542171] smpboot: CPU 1 is now offline
Feb  7 21:18:53 localhost kernel: [ 3993.552763] Broke affinity for irq 16
Feb  7 21:18:53 localhost kernel: [ 3993.552767] Broke affinity for irq 23
Feb  7 21:18:53 localhost kernel: [ 3993.552774] Broke affinity for irq 27
Feb  7 21:18:53 localhost kernel: [ 3993.552778] Broke affinity for irq 28
Feb  7 21:18:53 localhost kernel: [ 3993.553811] smpboot: CPU 2 is now offline
Feb  7 21:18:53 localhost kernel: [ 3993.568351] Broke affinity for irq 1
Feb  7 21:18:53 localhost kernel: [ 3993.568353] Broke affinity for irq 8
Feb  7 21:18:53 localhost kernel: [ 3993.568355] Broke affinity for irq 9
Feb  7 21:18:53 localhost kernel: [ 3993.568357] Broke affinity for irq 12
Feb  7 21:18:53 localhost kernel: [ 3993.568359] Broke affinity for irq 16
Feb  7 21:18:53 localhost kernel: [ 3993.568361] Broke affinity for irq 23
Feb  7 21:18:53 localhost kernel: [ 3993.568363] Broke affinity for irq 26
Feb  7 21:18:53 localhost kernel: [ 3993.568365] Broke affinity for irq 27
Feb  7 21:18:53 localhost kernel: [ 3993.568367] Broke affinity for irq 28
Feb  7 21:18:53 localhost kernel: [ 3993.569379] smpboot: CPU 3 is now offline
Feb  7 21:18:53 localhost kernel: [ 3993.581513] ACPI: Low-level resume complete
Feb  7 21:18:53 localhost kernel: [ 3993.581562] ACPI : EC: EC started
Feb  7 21:18:53 localhost kernel: [ 3993.581563] PM: Restoring platform NVS memory
Feb  7 21:18:53 localhost kernel: [ 3993.581915] Enabling non-boot CPUs ...
Feb  7 21:18:53 localhost kernel: [ 3993.601924] x86: Booting SMP configuration:
Feb  7 21:18:53 localhost kernel: [ 3993.601926] smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 1 APIC 0x1
Feb  7 21:18:53 localhost kernel: [ 3993.605684]  cache: parent cpu1 should not be sleeping
Feb  7 21:18:53 localhost kernel: [ 3993.605868] CPU1 is up
Feb  7 21:18:53 localhost kernel: [ 3993.626101] smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 2 APIC 0x2
Feb  7 21:18:53 localhost kernel: [ 3993.630007]  cache: parent cpu2 should not be sleeping
Feb  7 21:18:53 localhost kernel: [ 3993.630195] CPU2 is up
Feb  7 21:18:53 localhost kernel: [ 3993.650191] smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 3 APIC 0x3
Feb  7 21:18:53 localhost kernel: [ 3993.654260]  cache: parent cpu3 should not be sleeping
Feb  7 21:18:53 localhost kernel: [ 3993.654441] CPU3 is up
Feb  7 21:18:53 localhost kernel: [ 3993.660043] ACPI: Waking up from system sleep state S3
Feb  7 21:18:53 localhost kernel: [ 3994.121929] ehci-pci 0000:00:1d.0: System wakeup disabled by ACPI
Feb  7 21:18:53 localhost kernel: [ 3994.122047] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: System wakeup disabled by ACPI
Feb  7 21:18:53 localhost kernel: [ 3994.122366] ehci-pci 0000:00:1a.0: System wakeup disabled by ACPI
Feb  7 21:18:53 localhost kernel: [ 3994.122617] PM: noirq resume of devices complete after 16.560 msecs
Feb  7 21:18:53 localhost kernel: [ 3994.123375] PM: early resume of devices complete after 0.717 msecs
Feb  7 21:18:53 localhost kernel: [ 3994.124344] rtc_cmos 00:01: System wakeup disabled by ACPI
Feb  7 21:18:53 localhost kernel: [ 3994.131657] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Starting disk
Feb  7 21:18:53 localhost kernel: [ 3994.353778] usb 2-1.5: reset full-speed USB device number 3 using ehci-pci
Feb  7 21:18:53 localhost kernel: [ 3994.365806] usb 1-1.3: reset high-speed USB device number 4 using ehci-pci
Feb  7 21:18:53 localhost kernel: [ 3994.449779] ata1: SATA link up 3.0 Gbps (SStatus 123 SControl 300)
Feb  7 21:18:53 localhost kernel: [ 3994.450867] ata1.00: configured for UDMA/133
Feb  7 21:18:53 localhost kernel: [ 3994.517793] usb 2-1.7: reset high-speed USB device number 4 using ehci-pci
Feb  7 21:18:53 localhost kernel: [ 3994.529906] usb 1-1.4: reset high-speed USB device number 5 using ehci-pci
Feb  7 21:18:53 localhost kernel: [ 3994.607066] psmouse serio1: synaptics: queried max coordinates: x [..5664], y [..4682]
Feb  7 21:18:53 localhost kernel: [ 3994.652971] psmouse serio1: synaptics: queried min coordinates: x [1278..], y [1172..]
Feb  7 21:18:53 localhost kernel: [ 3994.693878] usb 1-1.5: reset full-speed USB device number 6 using ehci-pci
Feb  7 21:18:53 localhost kernel: [ 3996.661729] PM: resume of devices complete after 2538.071 msecs
```

Comment: You could use a python app as described [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/183516/how-do-i-detect-when-my-system-wakes-up-from-suspend-via-dbus-or-similar-in-a-py/184046#184046)

Comment: also look at /var/log/pm_suspend.log

Answer (score 0):

`/var/log` contains all the system log files. The `syslog` file is likely the one you'd want to check.